# Troubleshoot anion exchange column (Fe, Cr, Co separation)?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, radioactivity

I ran an anion exchange column to separatate Fe, Cr, Co from solution of concentrated HCl.  The column was Dowex 1x8, 200-400 mesh, diameter < 0.5 cm, lenth 7 cm.  A gradient of acid concentrations was used to elute: 12 M (1 mL), 9 M (3 mL), 4 M (3 mL), and water.  The metals were all radioactive isotopes (Cr-51, Co-60, and Fe-59) and Fe (III), Cr(III), Co(II) oxidation states.  I used an NaI(Tl) detector to determine when each of the metal ions eluted.

I intended the Cr to immediately elute as it forms only neutral or cationic species in HCl, then the Co to elute around 9-4M, and the Fe to elute when water was used.

The Cr and Fe did what I expected, but the Co eluted with the Fe (with the water instead of at 9-4M HCl), and the two peaks completely overlapped.

Does anyone know why this behavior might have been observed?  Could I do any better with a cation column instead?

Comment: In the original method described by Kraus and Moore ([_J. Am. Chem. Soc.,_ **1953,** _75_ (6), 1460–1462](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja01102a054)), Co(II) was eluted with 4 M HCl (not Co(III)).

Comment: @Loong Oops! that was a mistake, the Co was indeed Co (II) when I did it.